# Better format to write pojos with date in REST

Tags: java, rest, date, datetime, jodatime

I want to create an entity by the use of POST operation in REST, my first problem is that my class has an date parameter where I am using jodatime Datetime.

Something like:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
  ...
  private Date birthday;

  public void setBirthday(DateTime birthday) {
    this.birhday = convertDate(birthday);
  }
}
```

If I want to write an method such like this in REST:

```
@POST
public Response create(User user)
```

Do I need to transform something before call my DAO? With is the best practice?

Second point and I guess the worst, I have classes with list of subclasses, something like Event, Edition, Lecture and so on... An event has many editions with has many lectures, ... some of that classes have date parameters and in that cases I need more than yyyy-mm-dd, I need store the time zone digts.

If I want to do this:

```
@POST
public Response create(Event event)
```

And pass an event with editions, lectures and so on it will fail? Do I need create first event second editions than lectures and transform the date attributes first? Do I need to create an set method which accept Strings in my pojos and validate this just to work [for me this is kind of strange]?

What is the better solution to use date in REST?

Comment: Use Jackson + [jackson-datatype-joda](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda).

Comment: Shouldn't `LocalDate` be enough for a date like a birthday? Or do you need the birth time as well?

Comment: Thx @Matt Ball I will research Jackson-datetype-joda.

Comment: Thx as well @Tom, LocalDate can solve my problem in User, however an edition has an start date and end date, I will need the timestamp digits. I just did´t specified earlier because I thought that the solution would be the same. I will edit it

Comment: Avoid POJOs Hermanos

Comment: Yeah @hfontanez I avoid them as much as I can. I totally disagree with the anemic problems that POJOS bring. I just said it to simplify the problem. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Jacksob-datatype-joda as @Matt Ball said and worked